# C - Pointers and Memory

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

I am a little confused, say in this example code;

```
ptrMem = createSharedMemory();  

ptrTemp = ptrMem;
```

`ptrMem` points to a shared memory location created by `SHMGET`

What is the point in having a `ptrTemp` pointing to it as well and how do I utilize both?

I want to loop through the memory and assign random numbers, e.g.;

```
ptrTemp = ptrMem;       
for(nCount = 0; nCount < 24; nCount++)
        {   
            x = rand() % 10000;
            *ptrTemp++ = x;
        }
```

The situation is having a client and a server which communicated through shared memory. There needs to be a character or something similar which indicates to the other process that they can do their processing. So for example, after the above loop has finished; `*ptrMem='*'`.

Comment: one you use to process allocated memory other you keep memorize to free later in your code.

Comment: Depends on the rest of the code e.g.  you could increment one to go through the memory

Comment: There are a lot of reasons you might do that.  Can you add more information?

Comment: So for example, I want to loop through the memory and add random integers; `ptrTemp = ptrMem; x = rand() % 10000; *ptrTemp++ = x;`. Why would I use `ptrTemp` here and not `ptrMem`

Answer (score 2):

It's because in the loop you *change* the pointer `ptrTemp`. After doing `ptrTemp++` the pointer no longer points to the original memory.

Answer (score 1):

> - What is the point in having a ptrTemp pointing to it as well and how do I utilize both?

It's the same idea as a "head" pointer in a linked list.

```
ptrTemp = ptrMem;     // here both pointers point to the start
                      //  of your shared memory location
```

As you run through you loop you perform this again and again:

```
*ptrTemp++ = x;
```

Now `ptrTemp` doesn't point to the start of your shared memory location anymore. In this specific example, you know that you looped 24 times (did 24 increments to your pointer) so you could use pointer arithmetic and "back off" the address, but why bother? For a few extra bytes you can just use a new pointer and always have a handy reference to the start of the buffer which will most likely need to be passed/referenced.

Keep in mind the name `ptrTemp` has "Temp" in the name, implying it's for some sort of temporary storage.

---

**EDIT:** The `*` operator is to dereference a pointer (or declare it as such). So in your code:

```
ptrTemp = ptrMem; // Assigning one pointer to another, no need for the * here since
                  // they are both pointers.

*ptrTemp++ = x; // here you are assigning a value to the memory pointed to by ptrTemp
                // to assign a value you need to dereference, then we increment ptrTemp
```

> - if I wanted to print the memory out, I'd have to do; ptrTemp = ptrMem, right?

Not really, that would just set the temp pointer back to the start of your shared memory buffer. If you wanted to print the *contents* of the memory out you could simply do:

```
for(nCount = 0; nCount < 24; nCount++)
    printf("%p: %d\n", ptrMem+nCount, *(ptrMem+nCount));
```

this doesn't change what ptrMem is pointing out (because we never overwrite it) we want to know what memory address (ptrMem+nCount) has what value (the dereferenced version of that) so we print a `"%p"` (pointer format string) and a `"%d"` (int format string)

Comment: Right okay, I understand that bit now! Would you mind explaining one more detail for me? Before the loop I do `ptrTemp = ptrMem` (no asterisk), in the loop; `*ptrTemp++` (note asterisk) then after, if I wanted to print the memory out, I'd have to do; `ptrTemp = ptrMem`, right? But why is there no asterisk needed here?

Comment: @TomSothcott - Does that edit help clarify your additional questions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `prtTemp` if i'd need to change his value to access different memory areas of the shared memory.

In case i'd need to pointer to the first byte of the shared memory area i can use the untouched `ptrMem`

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of taste.

If you want to iterate through the memory by incrementing a pointer, then you need to keep a pointer to the beginning so it can be properly freed.

You could also use an index to iterate through the memory instead and not use the temporary pointer.

```
for(nCount = 0; nCount < 24; nCount++)
{   
    x = rand() % 10000;
    ptrMem[nCount] = x;
}
```

Most instances I've seen (or done myself) when using a pointer to iterate through a memory buffer rather than just using an index is when the amount to advance the pointer isn't consistent. For instance, if your buffer always has the same data type in each element the compiler can know how much to increment the pointer (or calculate an index offset) for you.

```
struct mystruct* ptrMem;
ptrMem[0]; // first element
ptrMem[1]; // second element

struct mystruct* ptrTemp = ptrMem;
*ptrTemp; // first element
ptrTemp++; // increments ptrTemp by sizeof(struct mystruct) bytes
*ptrTemp; // second element
```

In this case it's a matter of taste which one you wish to use.

If for instance the compiler can't know the structure of the data contained in the buffer, such as processing a midi file where the commands have variable lengths, it can be easier (more readable) to iterate a pointer one byte at a time. Still, the compiler knows the size of a byte so you could use an index here as well.